# postgres: how to create table "if not exists" but ONLY if the schemas match?

Tags: postgresql

[from the postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> IF NOT EXISTS

> Do not throw an error if a relation with the same name already exists. A notice is issued in this case. Note that there is no guarantee that the existing relation is anything like the one that would have been created.

often we don't care if just the name matches, we care if the schema matches. is there any way specify "if not exists" but checking that the schema also matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the schema name in the table creation statement

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myshema.mytable AS ...
```